# "Incomplete Design" Problem: 2(between) x 2(within) x 2(within--but only in one between group!)

Tags: anova, experiment-design, fractional-factorial

**Problem:**

I am trying to analyze an experiment with the design in the title:

2(between) x 2(within) x 2(within--but only manipulated in one group)

My initial hunch was to run two separate 2 (between) x 2 (within) ANOVA.

However, this approach feels suspect to me.

Can I analyize this effectively in one model?

**Research Background:**

To give some context, this is a memory experiment with 16 stimuli, which were word-picture pairs.

The between-subject variable is type of memorization technique: passive reading or practice testing (e.g., word - ?).

One within-subject variable is type of final memory test prompt (e.g., word - ? or ?-picture).

The other within-subject variable only pertains to the practice-testing group. This is whether practice-test prompt matches the final test prompt (e.g., word-?/word-? OR ?-picture/?-picture) or does not match (word-?/?-picture OR ?-picture/word-?).

Thus, it's 2(learning technique: reading, pratice testing) x 2 (final-test prompt: word - ?, ?-picture) x 2 (practice-test/final-test match: match, no match).

Any help would be appreciated!